# De que manera puedo imitar un HorizontalScroollView que no sea usando uno?

Tags: java, android

me podrian ayudar diciendome alguna o algunas formas para imitar un *HorizontalScrollView*, ya que implemente uno y dentro le puse botones, pero cuando ejecuto la app (en el celular) se traba bastante, lo probe en otros celulares pero pasa lo mismo, no entiendo porque, o si tal vez hice algo mal al implementarlo. Las imagenes para los botones las tengo en el drawable no se si eso afecte en algo.

Código Java:

```
    peliculas = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutPeliculas);

    LinearLayout contenedorPeliculas = new LinearLayout(this);
    contenedorPeliculas.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayput.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    for (int i = 0; i < listaPeliculas.size(); i++ )
    {
        ImageView pelicula = new ImageView(this);
        pelicula.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(210,290));
        pelicula.setBackgroundResource(listaPeliculas.get(i).Fondo());
        pelicula.setId(i);
        pelicula.setOnClickListener(this);
        contenedorPeliculas.addView(pelicula);
    }

    peliculas.addView(contenedorPeliculas);
```

Código XML:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutPeliculas"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```